# Tracing a bezier curve from an image for a cocos2d game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, bezier

I was wondering if there is a tool that will allow me to construct/trace a closed bezier curve based on a background image?

Basically I have a background image that represents some 2d curve which could be of some weird shape like a race track and I want to place some items along this path.

I figured that if I can derive a quadratic bezier curve that will overlap the image I would be able to use the mathematical equations for this curve to compute individual points along its path..

Does anyone know if such tool exists? Is my approach reasonable or totally off and there is a much simpler solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest building it yourself. It shouldn't be too difficult to build a level creator where you add your own background image, place your bezier key points along where they need to be and export the points into a plist. It'll even give you room for extending it and customizing it for your game.

Also, if you're planning on tracing a path along a road for a racing game, consider constructing the background from smaller road/tree/grass sprites. This way you can give them specific properties (such as canDriveOn, canHit and so on) and based on customized behaviour defined for each one of them, your 'driveable' path would be derived implicitly.